# CircleCI Angular5 build is failing because the firebase secrets are missing

Tags: typescript, angular5, circleci, circleci-2.0

I have an Angular5 project using Typescript. In my local machine, the build is successful; however, CircleCi build fails because there is an import in the code that points to the firebase.config.ts file, which has my credentials and I don't want to check that into Github public repo.

The codebase is available at [github](https://github.com/mahmoodkhan/myblog).

My question is how do I setup CircleCI so that the build is successful without having to make the firebase.config.ts file public?

Comment: What would I do if I became a member of your team? How would I build the project? If you can answer this question, you can configure your build server.

Answer (score 0):

You normally keep credentials and stuff like that out of configs and especially out of repositories by putting these into specific environment variables. This is based on the best practices as set by https://12factor.net/

This way you can easily split up required settings and credentials between development/test/acceptation/production environments. This also allows you to turn on certain features that would make development/testing easier but lowers security, which is required on acceptation and production systems.

In regards to CircleCI, they've provided documentation on how to get your environment settings setup properly:
https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/

So effectively, you wouldn't want to make your config file public. You want it to read from the `ENVIRONMENT` and make sure you have your `ENV settings` outside of your repository for your local development system.

More basics in regards of using `ENV`: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-environment-variables

Comment: You have to try and look up things yourself in order to learn. First 2 Google results I got where also answers on StackOverflow: I searched for `typescript read environment variable`

Comment: You asked about reading environment variables. These can be set in numerous ways. Including setting them in the environment of CircleCI. The way of reading these into your files is a separate issue which you probably found answers to. Consider searching for how CircleCI sets environment variables.